# How can I change the colors of my highcharts piechart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using highcharts to make a piechart but I'm having trouble loading a custom color set for my chart.

Here is my code:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
     Highcharts.setOptions({
     colors: ['#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263',      '#6AF9C4']
    });
    return new Highcharts.Chart({


        chart: {
            renderTo: 'trailpiechart',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            backgroundColor: "#f8f8f8",
            margin: [20, 20, 20, 20]
        },


        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        title: {
            text: caption
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.y + ' links';
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            floating: false,
            borderRadius: 0,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: data
        }]
    });
    });
</script>
```

My pie chart works with this code but it only uses the default color pallet.

How do you specify a custom color set?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
 colors: ['#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4']
});
```

Look the following example
http://jsfiddle.net/8QufV/

Comment: I have tried this but, my legend color are getting changed but the pie-chart color is not changing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28840716/3660648 Please check this. We have to add `color` property at series level.

Answer (score 14):

For those of you that prefer to initialize the color in the configs, you could simply put the colors in the plotOptions portion of the config object like so:

```
...,
plotOptions: {
  pie: {
   colors: [
     '#50B432', 
     '#ED561B', 
     '#DDDF00', 
     '#24CBE5', 
     '#64E572', 
     '#FF9655', 
     '#FFF263', 
     '#6AF9C4'
   ],
   allowPointSelect: true,
   cursor: 'pointer',
   dataLabels: {
     enabled: false
   },
   showInLegend: true
 }
},
...
```

Comment: How would one initialise tooltip functions using the config method?

Answer (score 7):

I think what you need to do is set the colors using theme instead of setOptions as follows:

```
Highcharts.theme = {colors: ['#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', 
                             '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4']});
```

Comment: If you go to [Pie Chart Demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic/grid) and then click on 'View visual theme' you will see how to manipulate the whole theme.

Comment: hi Todd color not changing by using your above code .still it showing default colors of pie chart

Answer (score 2):

To answer @Loko Web Design's question https://stackoverflow.com/a/38794379/7475250

> Is there a webpage that says to what each of the "colors" corresponds? All the answers here show something like:
>
> ```
> colors: ['#333', '#CB2326', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#CB2326', '#6AF9C4']
> ```
>
> But what do #333, #CB2326, etc. actually change? Obviously I can just
>   change them and see what changes, but it would nice to have this
>   reference available somewhere.

The color docs are available [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colors). Although helpful they do not describe what changing a specific color actually does. Below is my best description.

The colors prop gives Highcharts the colors you would like the chart to loop through.  For example if you had the following color prop.

```
colors: ['blue', 'green']
```

Your pie slices would alternate between blue and green.  Changing blue to red your colors would then alternate between red and green. Test it with the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjax/ab0mnq0f/2/)

Expanding the color list increases the number of colors before repeating.

```
colors: ['blue', 'green', 'yellow']
```

Would repeat the colors if more than 4 slices are in your dataset.

Answer (score 1):

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
 colors: ['#333', '#CB2326', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#CB2326',      '#6AF9C4']
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a webpage that says to what each of the "colors" corresponds? All the answers here show something like:

```
colors: ['#333', '#CB2326', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#CB2326', '#6AF9C4']
```

But what do #333, #CB2326, etc. actually change? Obviously I can just change them and see what changes, but it would nice to have this reference available somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In highcharts.css there's a section called "Default colors". After I deleted this section, I could use custom colors. Anyway, I guess you do not need highcharts.css if you use version v5.0.4 or higher.

Comment: Lot of answers saying to use "colors" property, but just this one has worked!

I'd suggest to create a css override to .highcharts-color-0 to .highcharts-color-9 with colors you want!

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0.5).get('rgba')]

In high charts inbuilt colors we have. So you need to change the path of the color[0] or [1]........[6]