# Highcharts - column color different from color in legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have defined custom color for data in series for highcharts column chart

```
data: [{y: 1234.5, color: '#234567'}, ...]
```

Sample code

```
var options = {
    chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
title: {
    text: 'Period'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Cat 1', 'Cat 2'];
    })
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: null
    }
},
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0
    }
},

series: [
  {
    name: 'Dog',
    data: [{y: 1, color: '#FF0000'}, {y: 1.45, color: '#FF0000'}]
  },
  {
    name: 'Cow',
    data: [{y: 2, color: '#CCCCCC'}, {y: 5.00, color: '#CCCCCC'}]
  },
  {
    name: 'Bird',
    data: [{y: 3, color: '#BBBBBB'}, {y: 3.45, color: '#BBBBBB'}]
  },
]

};
```

However for one column color in legend is different from corresponding column as shown in picture:

http://prntscr.com/6c2o25

I don't see it is possible to define custom color for xAxis > categories but only inside data entry.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post some code apart from data array?

Comment: I just added highcharts config object

Comment: Why do you set color on point level, not on series.level ? Like `name: "dog", color: "red" ` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are setting your colors on the point level instead of the series level.

This leaves the series colors as the Highcharts default colors despite your column being the color you wanted.

The series color is what determines the legend icon color.

So this:

```
name: 'Dog',
data: [{y: 1, color: '#FF0000'}, {y: 1.45, color: '#FF0000'}]
```

Should be:

```
name: 'Dog',
color: '#f00',
data: [1,1.45]
```

Updated fiddle with colors set at the `series` level:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/8xo2jayg/

Comment: Thanks, in their documentation there is no "color" property in series part

http://prntscr.com/6cc7ks

Comment: The section you need for this is plotOptions->series, rather than the top level series object.  Found here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.color